# How to set a variable storing a string ID as a jQuery element so can use .offset() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which on an anchor link click should get the hash from the URL and then scroll to the anchor point (an element exists with an ID of that hash) with some offset size for a fixed header.

`anchorLink` appears to be undefined as .offset().top returns "cannot read property of undefined".

The output of `anchorLink` is `#my-anchor` which is correct - so maybe it's just not a jQuery object and therefore can't get the offset and top?

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e) {

    console.log(location.hash);
    var anchorLink = $( location.hash.replace(/^#/, '') );
    var offsetSize = $(".site-header").innerHeight();
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: anchorLink.offset().top - offsetSize }, 500);

});
```

Comment: It's easy enough to test: `console.log(anchorLink.length)`

Comment: `location.hash.replace(/^#/, '')` will not be equal to `#my-anchor` - it might be `my-anchor` but you're explicitly removing the leading `#` - unless your url has `##my-anchor` you'll need to use `var anchorLink = $("#" + location.hash....`

Comment: Gotcha! I could have sworn it had the hash at the start! Thanks